# Divergence (or second derivative) of circle

Tags: derivatives, circles, partial-derivative

The circle has the uniform shape because a second derivative is 1. That is an intuitive guess - the line turns around at constant rate (i.e. the first derivative changes at constant rate), which means that it is not dependent on x and y coordinates. If the rate of the turn would increase, one would get inward spiral, etc. The shape of the circle is uniform so the step of the turn in x variable and in y variable is the same.

How to support this mathematically? Should a divergence be computed? I tried simply computing derivates however the circle is not a function, it is an equation and it is quickly very confusing.

Comment: $x^2 + y^2 = R^2$ can be simply turned to $f(x) = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ and $g(x) = -\sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$. $f$ and $g$ together form a circle (two operators are needed to work with functions, while circle is not a function, as it returns two values for every $x$). It's more complicated but still possible for more common form of circle equation $(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = R^2$.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski: I tried calculating and also tested this on WolframAlpha, but sophisticated fraction appears after entering d/dx(d/dx(y=sqrt(r^2 - x^2))). What could be wrong with this query? Should I sum also y derivative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can parametrize the circle by$$\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to\mathbb{R}^2,\quad t\mapsto(\cos t,\sin t).$$Since for every $t$ we have$$\|\dot{\gamma}(t)\|=\|(-\sin t,\cos t)\|=1,$$this is an arc length parametrization. Hence, the curvature at a point is given by the norm of the second derivative. But$$\|\ddot{\gamma}(t)\|=\|(-\cos t,-\sin t)\|=1$$is constant, and so the circle has a constant curvature.